# PHP: Can not use global variable in function to connect mysqli

Tags: php, function, variables, mysqli, global

I've been searching stack to get my answer, but nothing fixed my problem. So here's my shot:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db');
function GetArticle() {
  global $conn;
  $sql = "sql query";
  $getresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  ..
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I put $conn inside the function, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: How'd you know the `$conn =` assignment actually resided in the global scope?

Comment: Yes, if you put that as is in a file it should work.

Comment: Hey mario, i've tried to use a simple variable and return it by the function with the global, worked fine. only the database connection wont work

Comment: Going off of @AbraCadaver the best thing would be to put your connection code in a separate file and include that connection file in future files( which connect to the a db )

Comment: Try to get error with `mysqli_connect_error()` or `mysqli_error()`. Maybe you closed connection somewhere above or did not use `mysqli_free_result()` in some of your previous queries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your exact situation, but in general I do not see the benefit to using `$conn` as global. Your function depends on a mysqli connection in order to work, so just make the connection a function parameter.

```
function GetArticle($conn) {
  $sql = "sql query";
  $getresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  ..
}
```

Then after you have established your connection, you can call the function with your connection object as its argument.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db');
$article = GetArticle($conn);
```

I think this is a more manageable approach than trying to keep track of whether `$conn` is available in global scope before calling the function.

Comment: it's that i have all my functions in one php file.
but anyway, i fixed it by using mysql instead mysqli

Comment: I remember once in an apartment I was renting, I asked the management to fix one of the bedroom doors that was hung at a slight angle, which prevented it from closing properly and left a sizable gap above the top corner. The maintenance guy fixed it by sawing off the bottom corner of the door.